# Determine context inside member function being called by a pointer to it

Tags: c++, c++-cli, pointer-to-member

The title might not be explanatory enough, since the problem is hard to describe.

I have the following (simplified) two data structures in a Library which I cannot change:

```
class A;

typedef void(A::*AMemFunc)();
struct FooBar
{
    AMemFunc func;
    std::string identifier;
};

class A
{
    private:
        std::vector<FooBar *> theCollection;

    public:
        virtual ~A()
        {
            for (auto fooBar : theCollection)
            {
                delete fooBar;
            }

            theCollection.clear();
        }

        void AddToCollection(AMemFunc func, const std::string &identifier)
        {
            FooBar *newFooBar = new FooBar();
            newFooBar->func = func;
            newFooBar->identifier = identifier;

            theCollection.push_back(newFooBar);
        }

        void RemoveFromCollection(const std::string &identifier)
        {
            for (auto collectionIt = theCollection.begin(); collectionIt != theCollection.end(); collectionIt++)
            {
                FooBar *currentFooBar = *collectionIt;
                if (currentFooBar->identifier == identifier)
                {
                    collectionIt = theCollection.erase(collectionIt);
                    delete currentFooBar;
                    currentFooBar = nullptr;
                }
            }
        }

        const std::vector<FooBar *> &getTheCollection() const
        {
            return theCollection;
        }
};
```

The member function is invoked inside the library and is entirely out of my control. Now a user of the library may create sub-classes of A and add a member function to the collection, as follows:

```
class B : public A
{
    public:
        B()
        {
            AddToCollection((AMemFunc)&B::Test, "MyIdentifier");
        }

        void Test()
        {

        }
};
```

Now I want to create a C++/CLI wrapper for this functionality (inheriting from A and being able to assign a member method). The details of creating a B instance is omitted for simplicity's sake:

```
ref class WrapperB
{
    public:
        delegate void AMemFuncDelegate();

        void AddToCollection(AMemFuncDelegate ^func, String ^identifier)
        {
            // Do stuff
        }
};
```

But I am presented with a problem of how I could possibly allow dynamic creation of member function pointers.

These are the sub-par solutions I came up with so far:

- Ignore the unmanaged std::vector altogether and manage it completely in c++/cli (details are ommitted, but it is possible). The drawback is that the C++ side has no interop capabilities (or knowledge about) with the managed functions.
- Define N member functions in `B` which transmit a unique id to the managed side which can be coupled to a delegate. This limits the amount of things you can add to the collection and gives a lot of code clutter and duplication. Also when a user calls `RemoveFromCollection` I cannot detect a removal of a `FooBar` (no virtual destructor either) and decouple the managed delegate. But this is really a problem in all situations

Both solutions I came up with thus-far are non-ideal and I'm not sure if I'm missing something here.

Edit: I cannot use c++11 or higher on the unmanaged side.

Comment: @AndyG while it is certainly very bad practise to use C-style casts in C++, I think this should be fine as long as the member pointer is only used with objects that are actually of type `B`. The C-style cast here [should correspond](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/expr.cast#4.2) to a `static_cast` since `static_cast` can convert from a pointer to member of a class to a pointer to member of one of its base classes [\[expr.static.cast\]/12](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/expr.static.cast#12)?

Comment: How does the library actually use the member function pointer? I would imagine it must somehow use it as a sort of callback? If that is the case, does this callback get any information that you could use to map it back to a particular delegate?

Comment: @MichaelKenzel: I suppose the code shown is safe, so long as when it actually calls the function, it's casted back to an appropriate type.

Comment: @AndyG I don't think there is a need to cast back. The only thing that is necessary is that the dynamic type of the object the member pointer is used with is actually the correct type (`B` in this case) [\[expr.mptr.oper\]/4](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/expr.mptr.oper#4). At least as far as my understanding goes, member pointers are supposed to have any necessary offset for the this pointer encoded in their value…

Comment: @MichaelKenzel: Well I'll be. Looks like you're 100% right. Thanks for pointing that out. Didn't know about the rule for the dynamic type. I had thought it was undefined but worked just because the offsets lined up by chance; in a multi-inheritance situation I assumed they would not. Thanks.

Comment: @AndyG I also wasn't all that sure until I looked it up. This sort of stuff is just not something that I (or anyone I'd ever known) end up using on a regular basis because it's just…something else… ;-)

Comment: @MichaelKenzel The library iterates through a collection with `A` pointers and uses `getTheCollection`. Then it invokes the member function using the `A` pointer and member function pointer. In the real situation `FooBar` contains a few more fields, but none that can be used to do anything (they need to remain the same or they will break things). The member function is called without any arguments. I actually have the same problem with another Register_X function that actually takes 2 arguments, but as I have no control over the calling, I cannot use them to my advantage

Comment: Inside the function that iterates the `A` collection `identifier` is known, but never passed to the 'delegate'.

Comment: I'm afraid the only solution I can come up with in this case would be to dynamically allocate thunks that forward/translate the member function call to a call of a delegate. It's possible to do this, however, note that the fundamental problem here is the design of this collection and nothing else. So if at all possible, I would consider getting rid of this collection and replacing it with something more sensible…

Comment: @MichaelKenzel Thanks for the response. Yeah thats the entire problem with the question, I'm unable to change things. I think I'm going to go with accepting the limitations and just separating the managed side from the unmanaged side in this case.